# Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. If $(|a_n|)$ is convergent then $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove this proposition?

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. If $(|a_n|)$ is convergent then $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

If $(|a_n|)$ converges to $L$ then $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n>n_0 \implies ||a_n|-L|<\epsilon$.

I got stuck here.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

There are either infinitely many non-negative elements of $a_n$ or infinitely many non-positive elements. Consider the subsequence consisting of these.

Answer (score 3):

Use Bolzano Weierstrass theorem. 
Every bounded sequence have subsequence convergence.